# Apeending Datetime to the primary key on save

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

What i want to do is to make my primary keys to append current datetime stamp with them when saved in database.
For Example
The very first value of primary key column would include the datetime as *24-02-2016 4:35* so it would be like

```
240220164350   (The last digit is the auto increment value and previous ones is date and time)
```

and then the second may be like

`240220164361`

And it should also be auto incremented.

Any ideas on how i can achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid idea because it *can* lead to collisions and it's also denormalizing the data plus it adds more complexity than required. I see totally no reason to go for such a silly design decision. Simply use two fields.

However, if you like to do stupid things here we go: Don't use autoincrement on the DB field and write your custom method and call it in the `beforeSave()` callback that increments the number of records and adds the timestamp. You must set the id manually and only when the entity is new.

The problem you'll face is that when you delete records the count won't be right. If you have [1,2,3] and delete 2 your next id will be 3 again. So you'll have to store the total count that was ever saved persistent somewhere else. Where and how and especially *reliable* is your problem.

Another solution would be to use two fields, let the DB increment the id and use SQL's concat() to combine both together into a new aliased field. Or do it [using a virtual property of an entity](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields).

Or do another save() after the record was created and combine both fields values and saven them into a third field.

Comment: I know but my client wants it from me.. I have an idea for this.. What if before displaying the id i append the created field with it? Will it be of more ease?

Comment: Like I said, save them separated from each other and in this case use a virtual field on an entity or directly concatenate them using concat() on the database level. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a good idea at all. you should use two field `id` and `time`. 
however, you can use **PHP** `time()` function it returns current Unix timestamp.

more info **http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php**